# PHP + WordPress: Undefined variable: arr_Visited

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I seem to be having issues getting the items in an array:

header.php

```
<?php
  $arr_Visited = array("V" => "2");
?>
```

single.php

```
<?php
    var_dump($arr_Visited);
?>
```

Which gives me this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: arr_Visited in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/themes/new_theme/single.php on line 4

Which is this **var_dump($arr_Visited);**

however when I add **var_dump($arr_Visited);** under the array decleration in the header.php file it works:

> array(1) { ["v"]=> string(1) "2" }

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: Do you realize this array is in one file and accessing in another  `header.php` and `single.php`

Comment: I thought that they will render as one whole project? I have defined the post id in the header and us it in the side bar. Is there anyway to get it to cross over?

Comment: use `include` or `require`. Check post id must have some of the link with both

Comment: @Spartan the single.php has the WordPress Function get_header() which includes it.

Comment: you can make the one in header.php a global variable and then access it in your single.php

Comment: @IgorYavych I added 'global' before the array declaration but it crashed the page

Comment: @JamesG well, you did it incorrectly then. `global $arr_Visited; $arr_Visited = array("V" => "2");` in header.php.`global $arr_Visited; if(isset($arr_Visited)){var_dump($arr_Visited);}` in single.php

Comment: As a side-not, this is *not the WordPress way*.  You should not have logic / code like this in your theme templates, they should all live in your functions.php file.